# DIV background-image stops after scrolling in 2 columns CSS design

Tags: css, height, background-image

I made a template with 2 columns with CSS like this picture.

[image: My template]

The main div is **main**. It has 2 dives inside itself. DIV **sider** has a background-image. And I want to show it always. Now, I have 2 problems. First, it does not cover height of screen by default unldess I set a `min-height=...` for it. Second, if I do it, after scrolling the page, the background images won't repeat to cover whole of screen height.

```css
html {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    height: 100%
}

body {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:9pt;
    color:#333333;
    line-height:200%;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    background: #f0f0f0 url('../images/bg-radial-gradient.gif') fixed 230px top no-repeat;
    width:100% !important;
    height: 100%
}

#main {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%
}

#sidebar {
    width:231px !important;
    float:left;
    background-image:url('../images/sidebar_bg.PNG');
    min-height: 100%;
}

#container {
    float:left;
    padding:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    width:70%;
    min-height: 100%
}
```

### What's the problem?

Edit: This is my backgroun image
 [image]

Comment: Please use the fully-qualified path to the image (http://) so we can see it in the example.

Comment: where's ur HTML?.. use [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net),else live page??

Comment: @VivekChandra I provided jsFiddle for it. Did you see it ?

Comment: @Diodeus have you any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO 1 : Unwanted white space**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dYYb/3/)

The additional space in the bottom is because of your `padding:25px;` ( Same as     `padding:25px 25px 25px 25px;`).There's an extra top padding + bottom padding which is givin your div additional `50px`.

If you do not want that additional space - Try this => [**DEMO 2 : without the white space**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dYYb/4/)

You can replicate the same effects of top and border 25px with this:

```
padding:0 25px;
margin:25px 0;
```

To avoid that extra unwanted space.

**Edit:**

The additional space is caused by the `margin:25px 0;`, if you remove it - you wont have that extra space.check this 
 [**DEMO 3 Removing unwanted space caused by Margin**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dYYb/5/)

**Edit 2 :**

Your problem is a well documented problem - Matching Columns Problem. There are loads of solutions you can try, here are a few :

1) [**javascript**](http://javascript-reference.info/the-matching-columns-script-matching-css-div-heights-with-javascript.htm)

2) [**Alter the Image (Hacky)**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

3) [**Pure CSS**](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm)

My fav => Option 2

I havnt personally explored the last one,but try it out.. :)

Hope it helps..

Comment: thank you for your post. It seems that the problem is solving. But there are 2 points. 1- I just escaped last `;` for each block. I don't think this is a problem in CSS. 2- In you 2nd demo, I see an extra space at the end of result when I scroll it. What is this for?

Comment: Semicolons for last line of block are NOT necessary and it's good practice to leave them out.

Comment: On large CSS files it can give a great performance (i.e. loading and executing) boost.